# Magento 2: Minicart Failed to load the "Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount" component

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, knockoutjs, mini-cart, coupon

I am working on MiniCart Extension in which I need a coupon code text box in my Minicart. For that I have overridden default.xml in my Custom Module but everytime It returns following error in the console. I think the layout is not able to find discount js however same js is there in the pub directory.

> Failed to load the "Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount"
>   component

This is the code inside default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_total_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="Mageants_AjaxShoppingCart::cart/minicart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>


                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>

                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Help will be appreciated. Thank You In Advance.

Answer (score 4):

if that's still relevant, here's the answer:

`Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount` requires `Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote`, which asks for `window.checkoutConfig.quoteData` on line 32:

`quoteData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteData,`

`window.checkoutConfig` is not available anywhere except the checkout page - it is set in `module-checkout/.../templates/onepage.phtml` on line 26:

`window.checkoutConfig = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() ?>;`

So, you are getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'quoteData' of undefined`.
After that, `url-builder` produces the same kind of error when trying to read `window.checkoutConfig.storeCode`.
You can see it if you set a breakpoint in `require.js` on line 883, where it handles such errors. Look at the stack trace printed in the console and click on the function call right before `onError` (it says `check`).